# QGIS Model Designer - Select by expression doesn't work

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, select-by-expression

I try to do a simple model with the Model Designer of QGIS and I have an issue with the algorithms `Select by expression`.

[image]

And when I want to check the validity of the model the explanation is just : ***The Algorithm is not available***

[image]

You can see the settings I used for `Select by expression`

[image]

Does someone know why I can't use Select by expression ?

Moreover, you can see my QGIS settings with the following screenshot

[image]

OK, as Babel said I tried to use `Extract selected features` and it works but only if I set a ***model output*** also for this algorithm
[image]

When I set ***algorithm output*** it doesn't work

Comment: Hi Sof, welchome to GIS SE. Great to have you here. I think we need a bit more information - so you were - obviously - able to select the algorithm `Select by expression`. Can you show us the settings? What QGIS version do you use? What happens when you try to delete and add again the algorithm?

Comment: Hello Babel, I use the 3.22.4 version of QGIS (Białowieża) on a Ubuntu laptop 22.04.2 LTS. When I try to delete and again the algorithm it doesn't change : the model is still invalid

Comment: Which settings did you make in the `Select by expression` algorithm? Please show a screenshot of this

Comment: I have just done it. Do you think the expression is the cause of the problem ?

Comment: The expression should be fine, as long as you have an attribute field with the name  `NATURE`. The algorithm selects all features where the value of this field is `Type autoroutier`, `Route à 2 chaussées` or `Bretelle`. See my answer to see what (probably) went wrong.

Comment: Just an advice: when posting screenshots, try to make the dialog windows as small as possible. You 2nd and 3rd screenshot contain a large white/gray empty area that cover almost my whole screen without adding any information - clip the part from your screenshot that does not contain any relevant information or resize the windows before capturing a screenshot.

Comment: Add Extract selected Features algorithm and than share your model. Even better if you could also share an extract of your data.

Comment: As I said above it works with Extract selected features (when I set Model output and not when I set Algorithm output). Thank you Babel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not set any valid input for `Modify current selection by`, it is empty. If you want to create a new selection, set the icon to the left to `Value` (icon `123` instead of the gear icon) and choose an option, e.g. `creating new selection`.

[image]

Use an `Extract selected Features` algorithm after the `Select by expression` algorithm, then use this as input for `Clip` algorithm.

Comment: When I do that, it is strange. The model is valid and I can run it. But when I run it the selection by expression was not done. Only the clip was done

Comment: So you should post the `Clip` settings as well. Or try to use a `Extract selected Features` algorithm after the `Select by expression` algorithm, then use this as input for `Clip`.

Comment: As I say above I confirmed it works (with Model output). Thank you Babel